# Translate string with variable and html

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I am trying to translate a string by using `translate.csv` located in `theme` but translation is not working.

Here is my string

```
"To check your Gift card information, please click <a href="%s">here</a>.","klik <a href="%s">her</a> for at tjekke din gavekortskode."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to double the double quotes for it to work.
So if you want the text printed as `To check your Gift card information, please click <a href="%s">here</a>.` you have to add this in the translate file

```
"To check your Gift card information, please click <a href=""%s"">here</a>.","klik <a href=""%s"">her</a> for at tjekke din gavekortskode."
```

Comment: It works but.... Why double quotes? :/

Comment: that's how magento parses the csv files. If you need double quotes inside the string you need to add double double quotes.

Comment: And this is also the string passed to $this-__("To check your Gift card information, please click <a href=""%s"">here</a>.") is also with double ""?

Comment: No. What you use inside `__()` should have single quotes.